# redis: enable a disabled command at run time

Tags: redis

This is a production instance of redis 2.8.13 on centos.

In our redis.conf, we have this:

```
rename-command CONFIG ""
```

And now.... we want to run the latency monitor which requires that we use the CONFIG command.

We have root access, this is our own dedicated server. Is it possible to modify the conf file and reload the config without restarting redis? (This is a production system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

redis doesn't have a way to reload redis.conf without restarting. You will need to restart redis.

This time, take careful note of the example and the warning given in redis.conf:

```
# Command renaming.
#
# It is possible to change the name of dangerous commands in a shared
# environment. For instance the CONFIG command may be renamed into something
# hard to guess so that it will still be available for internal-use tools
# but not available for general clients.
#
# Example:
#
# rename-command CONFIG b840fc02d524045429941cc15f59e41cb7be6c52
#
# It is also possible to completely kill a command by renaming it into
# an empty string:
#
# rename-command CONFIG ""
#
# Please note that changing the name of commands that are logged into the
# AOF file or transmitted to slaves may cause problems.
```

Comment: Yup.... gotta restart.... ack!

Comment: is there a way to get all the disabled redis command from redis ?