# Re-enabling commands in a cluster environment

Tags: kubernetes, redis, bitnami, helm

we are running Redis as a container in a Kubernetes cluster (v1.21.14-gke.3000) where it is installed via Helm.  Helm uses the Bitnami image, which disables the FLUSHALL command.  As with [this article](https://serverfault.com/questions/771547/redis-enable-a-disabled-command-at-run-time?newreg=3d569604038f47e8bf26afbb16904fa9), we want to re-enable Redis command but editing the configuration file is not feasible.  is there an alternative?

below is my `helmfile.yaml`:

```yaml
repositories:
- name: bitnami
  url: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

environments:
  dev:
    values:
      - existingSecret: 'redis-secret'
      - redisVersion: 17.3.8
  prod:
    values:
      - existingSecret: 'redis-secret'
      - redisVersion: 17.3.8

releases:
- name: redis
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
  chart: bitnami/redis
  version: "{{ .Values.redisVersion }}"
  installed: true
  recreatePods: true
  values:
    - values.yaml.gotmpl
```

and the corresponding `values.yaml.gotmpl`:

```yaml
auth:
  enabled: true
  existingSecret: {{ .Values.existingSecret }}

global:
  storageClass: 'premium-rwo'
  redis:
    password: "***"
replica:
  replicaCount: 1
master:
```

Comment: Hi Erick Calder welcome to S.F. You'll want to [edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1114927/edit) and include the details of your install, such as the chart version and any `--values` or `--set` you used, since as written no one can *guess* what you've done or look up the docker image to have any context for your question. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel thanks for the constructive criticism.  I've added the relevant files, which should be enough (I think) as context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after pulling my hair for a time I figured out the answer.  I can use the `disableCommands` value, which has to be handed to both the master and the replica like this:
and the corresponding `values.yaml.gotmpl`:

```yaml
master:
  disableCommands: []
replica:
  disableCommands: []
```